# Excel average based on row and column values

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, average

I would like to calculate the average (and other summary statistics) of algae counts based on the algal group (Column B) and the month (collection dates are in row 1). The first few columns and rows look like this:

```
row B---------------------C-------------------D

Algal Group -------6/5/2000 ----------7/5/2000-----etc.

Cyanobacteria-------5---------------------60        
Bacillariophyta-------2---------------------40      
Xanthophyta-------[blank]---------------30
```

I've tried using the standard AVERAGEIFS combined with the MONTH forumla, but I think the row of dates is throwing it off. I've also tried inserting a new row below the dates (i.e., row 2) with the Month of the collection date in row 1, and referring to that column in an AVERAGEIFS. That didn't work either. I've also tried entering it as an array formula. The dates are C1:DW1, Algae Groups are B2:B246. Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Are these filled with formulas?  as in the blank is it truly blank no formulas?

Comment: They are hard-entered values so a blank cell truly is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array formula like this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((MONTH($C$1:$E$1)=H8)*($B$2:$B$4=H9)*($C$2:$E$4<>""),$C$2:$E$4))
```

Being an Array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Would you mind explaining why you need to use the asterisk (*) in the formula?

Comment: The condition portion of the IF statement is three TRUE/FALSE statements.  TRUE/FALSE can be used in Math as 1/0 respectively.  So I have a math statement with three variable, if any return false it resolves to 0 because anything multiplies by 0 is zero, which for the IF statement is FALSE.  So for it to return TRUE all three must be TRUE. The `*` is multiplication.  So when all three are TRUE it resolve to `1*1*1=1` and `1` is read by Excel as TRUE.